# Monotouch dispose viewcontroller as subview

Tags: xamarin.ios, viewcontroller, subviews

I Have a ViewController that I want to display over another viewController (like a popup), so I use this code:

```
MyViewController vc = new MyViewController();           
this.View.AddSubview(vc.View);
```

And it works fine, but I am not sure to unload it correctly since I am not able to interact with the background view anymore, I use this code (from the MyViewController class) to unload it:

```
foreach (UIView view in this.View.Subviews) {
    view.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```

How can I remove the subview within the second viewcontroller itself and enable the first view again?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The above is a really bad idea.

If you are creating a new View Controller, you should present the View Controller, not go behind that view controller's take its views and manage them elsewhere.

So you should be presenting your view controller, either pushing it, or modally activating it.   The details depend on the specifics of your containing view controller.